# How can I access a Django model's Enum from within a template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums, django-templates

My Django model class is as follows:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    CHOICE1 = "CHOICE1"
    CHOICE2 = "CHOICE2"

    FIELD_CHOICES = (
        (CHOICE1, CHOICE1),
        (CHOICE2, CHOICE2),
    )
    my_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        choices=FIELD_CHOICES,
        default=CHOICE1,
    )
```

I pass `my_instance` which is an instance of `MyClass` into the template. 
From within that template how can I do an if-else check on the possible values of my_field?

I do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
{% if my_instance.my_field == my_instance.__class__.CHOICE1 %}
    <p>BLAH BLAH1</p>
{% elif my_instance.my_field == my_instance.__class__.CHOICE2 %}
    <p>BLAH BLAH2</p>
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:**
I can pass the class `MyClass` into the template context and then use `MyClass.CHOICEX`. That works. But it seems wasteful to have to pass in the class itself in addition to the instance. Can't I get the Class from the instance and then use `CHOICEX`?

Comment: Use custom temlatetag or pass choices to request context in your view

Comment: I added an Edit that explains a bit more. Can I do it without passing in anything extra to the context?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access class variables from instance:

```
{% if my_instance.my_field == my_instance.CHOICE1 %}
    <p>BLAH BLAH1</p>
{% elif my_instance.my_field == my_instance.CHOICE2 %}
    <p>BLAH BLAH2</p>
{% endif %}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/5098707) for more information on class variables.